# How to fetch object data from an NSMutableArray for later use

Tags: objective-c

Before I start, I would like to explain that I am pretty new to Objective-C, however, I do understand the language enough to get to where I am at the moment.

I am looking for a solution for an app I am designing, it's basically a tennis application to track the scores of the players. 
I have my 'Game' class sorted, however when the time comes to save the game in some sort of 'set' class I cannot work out how to save the scores of each player for that particular game.

I have tried using a separate class called 'SetObject'.h&.m with only two values in SetObject.h which would be player1EndGameScore & player2EndgameScore (both NSNumber), then storing them in a NSMutableArray in the set class, however this has proven to be troublesome as I don't know if it is possible to access each score from the array individually for a particular game.

The whole reason for this is that I am attempting to display all of the previous scores of the games as the match progresses on my ViewController that displays the game information.

Any tips on how I may accomplish this are welcome.

Comment: Could you not simply save them to `NSUserDefaults`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `TennisGame` class that contains two `NSUInteger` properties that represent the points for player 1 and the points for player 2 for that game. Then a `TennisSet` class would have a `games` property that was simply an `NSMutableArray` of `Game` instances. Similarly, a `TennisMatch` class could have an `NSMutableArray` property to hold `TennisSet` instances.

You can serialize/deserialize these objects to and from the file system using [`NSKeyedArchiver`](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).

Comment: Thank you, it taken some more understanding and some more research in order to get this working.